# How to change org-babel interpreter location

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, config

Say I have my ditaa interpreter pointed to at `/home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/contrib/scripts/ditaa.jar`, how would I set it so it points to a different location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(setq org-ditaa-jar-path "/path/to/your/ditaa.jar")`

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I've been trying to find the right variable, but had no idea where to look.

Comment: Sometimes you can just guess if you have `counsel` package, for example, type `C-h v` (counsel-describe-variable) and `ditaa` to find all variables about `ditaa`.